# Trying to understand C++: Duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c++11

Here are the files responsible for this linker error (Only showing file, namespace and class names):

```
// PubSub.hpp:
#ifndef PubSub_hpp
#define PubSub_hpp
namespace PubSub {
class Publisher {}
}
}
#endif

// Client.hpp:
#ifndef Client_hpp
#define Client_hpp
#include "PubSub.hpp"
class Client {
}
#endif

// Scene.hpp:
#ifndef Scene_hpp
#define Scene_hpp
#include "Client.hpp"
class Scene {
}
#endif
```

The code compiles without errors in this state. But as soon as I introduce a variable in PubSub.hpp under the namespace **PubSub** like below:

```
// PubSub.hpp:
#ifndef PubSub_hpp
#define PubSub_hpp
namespace PubSub {
class Publisher {}
}
Publisher NetworkEventPublisher("someName");
}
#endif
```

I get the linker error in the title. I can find a workaround but I am trying to learn C++ so I'm asking what's the rule causing this?

Comment: Don't define objects in headers.

Comment: Shorter than expected :-) Thank you.

Comment: Related: [Static variables in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698043/static-variables-in-c/3698179#3698179). While about static variables in particular, the answer also covers your case: A misunderstanding what a header file actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But as soon as I introduce a variable in PubSub.hpp

If you include a PubSub.hpp in more than one translation unit (.cpp file) then your `NetworkEventPublisher` will be defined more than once, and this is what linker in complaining about.

The solution is to move:

```
Publisher NetworkEventPublisher("someName");
```

to implementation file (ie. PubSub.cpp). If you want other translation unit see it, then add to PubSub.hpp extern declaration : `extern Publisher NetworkEventPublisher;`

Answer (score 2):

That error happens because including this header file into more than one translation unit (.cpp/.cc file) creates an object in the translation unit with the same name (aka symbol).

If you need one instance of the class declare it in the header as `extern` and define in a .cc file.

If you need a copy in each translation unit, declare and define the object in the header as `const`, such objects are implicitly `static`.

Comment: Assuming he want to modify the object later, is it possible to declare as static?

Comment: @bkVnet It is possible.