# What is the difference between static and non static global

Tags: c

```
static uint32_t a[20] = {0};
```

and

```
uint32_t a[20] = {0};
```

I use both of them in the code

```
a[0] = 1;
```

and so on....

When I make the variable `static` and use it I get an error

```
variable "a" was declared but never referenced
```

but when I remove `static` things work fine.

In both the cases the array `a` is a global one.

The error is with the MACROS .

Array declaration is done and it is used by some platform and I don't see an error on that. Same code provides an error because this declaration/array is not used on other platform.

My bad !!!!

```
static uint32_t a[20] = {0};
void func()
{
 ...............
   #ifdef ABC

   a[0] = 1;

   #endif
 ................
}
```

Now compile on platform ABC no error compile on some non ABC platform there is an error.

Solution: Wrap global also under the respective macro

```
#ifdef ABC
static uint32_t a[20] = {0};
#endif
```

Comment: `static` means "this variable is not _directly_ accessible outside the unit/file", but I don't understand why you are receiving such error

Comment: If you get an error that a variable was declared but never references, odds are you declared it but never referenced it. (Perhaps you referenced a different variable with the same name.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yeah I am wondering what is wrong. I am using it the same array in my code.

Comment: I have compiled the code with `static uint32_t a[20] = {0};` using either gcc or llvm, got neither errors nor warnings.

Comment: @Gopi It told you what is wrong, you are declaring a variable but not referencing it. As I said, you might be referencing a different variable with the same name. Try removing all the declarations that it tells you are not referenced -- if your code still compiles and links, it was  right.

Comment: "When I make the variable static and use it I get an error"  How and where did you try to use the variable?

Comment: @Lundin In the same `.c` file . In one of the functions.

Comment: So you tried to use a static variable in the same .c file in which it was declared and you got an error? Can you post a minimal, complete, compilable piece of code that reproduces the error or warning so we can see it for ourselves?

Comment: Then there is some other error in your code not related to the use of `static`.

Comment: _things work fine._ it's apparent. For internal linkage, compiler can issue the diagnostic...

Comment: @Lundin Has it got anything to do with the compiler ? I mean is there any obvious bug. I am sure that I am using the variable in my function

Comment: Are you using this declaration inside an header file?

Comment: @Gopi There's no way we can know if we can't see the code. Sometimes the error message can be misleading. As an extremely silly example, imagine if somewhere in your code you had something like  `#define static static X`, you'd get very strange error messages when you declared something `static`. Give us enough code to reproduce the error and we'll tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @Gopi It has almost certainly something to do with a bug in the code which you have not shown us.

Comment: @Lundin Uff!!!! I found out what was the error. The code which was using this was under some macro which the declaration was not... Thanks all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Uff!!!! I found out what was the error. The code which was using this was under some macro which the declaration was not... Thanks all.

Comment: Ok I'll vote to close as "cannot be reproduced" then. It would perhaps be interesting for future readers if you could post the problematic code that caused the issue.

Answer (score 5):

The major difference is, when defined as `static`, the scope of the array is limited to the translation unit, while , without static, the scope in not limited to the translation unit.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.2

> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage class
>   specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.

So, in case of a `static` global, you cannot *use* that variable outside of the translation unit.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Gopi Can you explain what was unclear or what you need elaboration on?

Comment: Here is a post about [static variable in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698043/static-variables-in-c) - is it the same in C?

Comment: @user3078414 It is the same except C++ has one additional meaning: when you make a private member `static`, you only get one such member across all instances of that class.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin, great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static`

**Case 1 :** When used in `file scope`

Example :

```
static int x=0; // declared outside main() and all functions
```

means the the variable can be used only within the translation unit, ie the file which contains it.

So  you cannot do

```
extern int x; // from another file
```

**Case 2 :** When used in `block scope`

Example

```
somefunction()
{
static int x=0;
x++; // x acting as a counter here
}
```

The variable `x` stays put(or it is not reinitialized) during different invocations of the function. You can use it as a function variable, for example, as a counter to find how many times a function is called. The scope is limited to the function block.

---

Regarding the warning :

> variable "a" was declared but never referenced

The memory allocated for an automatic variable is freed when it goes out of context. But this is not the case with static variables. They stay put till the end of the execution. If you don't use a static variable, the compiler may warn you regarding this - I guess - so that you could avoid such a declaration.