# Static const variable declaration in a header file

Tags: c, compilation, header-files

If I declare static const variable in header file like this:

```
static const int my_variable = 1;
```

and then include this header in more than one `.c` files, will compilator make new instance per each file or will be "smart" enough to see it is `const` and will make only one instance for all the files?

I know I can make it extern and define it in one of `.c` files that include this header but this is what I am trying not to do.

Comment: There are unfortunately no named constants for arbitrary types in C. In your case you can get away with an enumeration. `enum { my_value = 1, };` This would have the effect that you probably want, enumeration constants have type `int` in C. You would not be able to take the address of such a beast.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I answered this at length [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698043/static-variables-in-c/3698179#3698179). That answer is for C++, but it holds true for C as well.

The translation unit is the individual source file. Each translation unit including your header will "see" a `static const int`. The `static`, in this context, means the scope of `my_variable` is limited to the translation unit. So you end up with a *separate* `my_variable` for each translation unit ("`.c` file").

The compiler would not be "smart" to create only one instance for all files, it would be *faulty*, because you *explicitly* told it not to do so (`static`).

Comment: The `extern` version has the unfortunate property that you can't make the value visible to the other TUs.

Comment: @JensGustedt: You mean compile-time visible, as opposed to run-time visible (which an `extern` variable certainly is). That is correct. Deleted that sidenote.

Comment: @DevSolar do you know if there is any way to force compiler to make one instance? I was told that in GCC there is an option that makes compiler comparing const variables like in my example and merge them to one but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Michał: From your question, it is a bit unclear what you use `my_variable` for, why you need there to be only one instance, and what you expect to achieve. That makes it a bit difficult to make suggestions at this point. If you just need one global variable you can take the address of, use `extern`, as it's the cleanest way to do it. If you need *compile-time visibility* (e.g. for array sizes), use either the `enum` trick pointed out by Jens, or the age-old `#define MAX_SIZE ...`.

Comment: @Michal: Using `extern` instead of `static`?

Comment: @AlterMann is this a question ? I meant something more like compiling option not like workaround option. It means leaving `static const`.

Comment: Yes it is a question, so you can not replace `static`with `extern`

Comment: The gcc option is `-fmerge-all-constants` and is non conforming as per the [doc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), and apply to strings and FP. Note also that there is a different behavior by default for `char *` or `char[]`. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077119/can-gcc-merge-duplicate-global-string-arrays)

Answer (score 3):

If you use address of that object - compiler surely creates one instance per each translation unit. If you use only value - it is probably smart enough to avoid creating of object at all - value will be inlined where need.

Comment: I don't get you, both the address and the value of the object are not accesible outside the unit due to the `static` keyword, isn't it?

Comment: @AlterMann Yes, scope of course is limited by `static` but if you e.g. want to print address of that variable or do some kind of address arithmetic (weird of course since it is not an array) - compiler can't silently optimize it and inline and obligated to allocate storage for it.

Comment: Ah, ok, _If you use address of that object_ confuses me, I was thinking in `&my_variable` as the address  of the variable, do you mean if the variable is used / not used?

Comment: Actually I mean presence or absence of `&my_variable` - if there is - storage must be allocated since code needs a valid address, if there is no - compiler may insert actual value directly: `foo(my_variable)` is effectively the same as `foo(1)` (since variable is `const` and has the same value during whole program lifetime) so there is no point to allocate any memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

However on a different note, for the very purpose, this could be done: `static constexpr auto variable_name = <variable_value>;` in your header file, for example:

```
static constexpr auto VARIABLE = "VARIABLE_VALUE";
```

Answer (score -3):

I guess it will make only one instance for all files. But you can verify it by calling it in different files and check its value

Comment: Guessing and testing with some compilers doesn't tell what the standard prescribes.