# Can GCC merge duplicate global string arrays?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

I've been wondering if it's possible to compile using GCC with some optimization flag to avoid have two duplicate arrays to the .rodata section? Thus, memory addresses would be the same. For example:

```
const char str [7] = "string";

const char str1 [7] = "string";


int printf (const char * format, ...);

int main (void) {

      if (str == str1)
          printf ("Equal memory addresses");

      return 0;

}
```

So in this example above, is it possible that somehow the compiler uses the same memory addresses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to merge duplicated or multiplicated string literals into one in GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977606/how-to-merge-duplicated-or-multiplicated-string-literals-into-one-in-gcc)

Comment: Yes, most likely only one copy of `"string"` is contained in the executable string-table and is referenced in each assignment. This is particularly true for those OS where string-literals are immutable and created in the read-only section of the executable. (there is no reason to duplicate what will not change) This isn't true for all OS's though, and there are compiler options that can control this behavior on some compilers.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: [Without `-fmerge-all-constants`, GCC will duplicate the string into two separate global variables](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AtPIv2) (though the exact behavior depends on whether your types are `const char *` or `const char [N]`). Of course, if the program is as simple as the OP's then the optimizer can optimize the whole thing away and then there won't be *any* strings in the resulting binary.

Comment: It will also do so with *optimizations* enabled without `-fmerge-all-constants`. Try compiling with `-Ofast`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Did you look at the example I linked to? Because it's using `-Ofast`.

Comment: Yep, and it says just exactly that `:)` *"Most optimizations are only enabled if an -O level is set on the command line."* E.g. `int main (void) { char *s1 = "string", *s2 = "string"; printf ("s1: %p\ns2: %p\n", (void*)s1, (void*)s2); }` compiled with `-Ofast` merges without anything further. Which I think is what you were saying, it just wasn't clear as an optimized program is still a conforming program.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips, guy. Using pointer to a string, I already knew that the compiler used the same address for the string, but I did not know how to do that with array, grateful

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin [It's standards-conforming to merge string literals, but not required](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7). Note that a pointer to a string literal is different from a string array, and is what I was originally referring to in my comment above about `const char*` vs `const char[N]`. If you create `const char*` that point to string literals, those strings may be merged. But if you create `const char[N]`, those strings *cannot* be merged (at least not without `-fmerge-all-constants`, which results in non-conforming behavior).

Comment: Ok, now we are on the same page, and yes I agree, conforming but not required. We were talking about opposite sides of the same coin. The `"string"` literal initializers themselves can be (and are) merged (but not required to be merged). The arrays will of course be separate storage. Thanks.

Comment: This is a dupe but the linked post is of lower quality. I closed the link as dupe to this one instead.

Answer (score 6):

GCC's `-fmerge-all-constants` (which also implies `-fmerge-constants`) will do the trick. [It's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> `-fmerge-all-constants`
>
> Attempt to merge identical constants and identical variables.
>
> This option implies `-fmerge-constants`. In addition to `-fmerge-constants` this considers e.g. even constant initialized arrays or initialized constant variables with integral or floating-point types. Languages like C or C++ require each variable, including multiple instances of the same variable in recursive calls, to have distinct locations, so using this option results in non-conforming behavior.

Note that GCC does not guarantee the constants will be merged, so you shouldn't rely on this for program behavior. It will attempt to merge what it can, but some constants may not be mergeable.

**Input code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char str1[7] = "string";
const char str2[7] = "string";

int main() {
    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
}
```

[**Output assembly:**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/2E6UF2)

```
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:str1
        call    puts
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZL4str2
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
str1:
        .string "string"
```

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. Sorry if I did not express myself so well, my English is bad, again thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was helpful! No worries about your English. You're English is actually pretty decent and understandable. English is a pretty terrible language, so I commiserate with anyone learning it.

Comment: Any idea of what `-flto` does by default?

Comment: @BrettHale: `-flto` won't merge constants like `-fmerge-all-constants` will. That said, string literals can still be merged across translation units, even without `-flto` (I just tried it on my system and all it takes is `-O1` or above to merge duplicae string literals across translation units; `-flto` was not required).