# Declaring a constant literal string with const reference versus const variable

Tags: c++

I have to name windows with constant literal strings. The names will be  referenced everywhere so I need to cache them with variables. My question is

Do I need to declare the variables as const references as follows

```
const string& srcWnd = "Source Window";
```

instead of

```
const string srcWnd = "Source Window";
```

?

Is there any difference?

Comment: Define "need" - both of those will construct `string` objects, what exact difference are you asking about?

Comment: @UnholySheep: Yes, what is the difference?

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit What exactly do you mean by "cache the names"?

Comment: If you want a reference to literal itself rather than to `std::string` object then you should write `auto const & srcWnd{"Source Window"};`

Comment: As far as you're concerned, those two lines are the same.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Does const reference avoid copying?

Comment: Probably similar question from earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498738/how-to-share-global-constants-with-minimum-overhead-at-runtime/55499098

Comment: @MichaelKenzel:Thank you, it is helpful!

Comment: If you are constructing `std::string` class instance then content of array baking string literal will be always copied.

Comment: Given that we're talking about window names here, do these really have to be `std::string` (assuming that `string` up there is `std::string`)? Because if you're concerned about efficiency/avoiding copying then the first thing you'll probably wanna do is not have it be an `std::string`…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: The names are of type `std:string`.

Comment: @ArtificialHairlessArmpit ok, then probably just go with the `const std::string` approach as suggested in the answer below. Just be aware that a global `std::string` will almost necessarily mean that you're copying the string from a string literal object into the buffer owned by the `std::string` at load time. If the names are expected to be `std::string` that's most likely just fine anyways…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any significant difference between the two, but I suggest using the plain `string` (option 2):

```
const string srcWnd = "Source Window";
```

You don't win anything by using a reference. And if you use a reference, the code becomes more obscure, because by using a reference you rely on [temporary lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary). If someone doesn't remember lifetime extension rules clearly, they might need to look them up just to be sure that the code is valid.