# Modifying rodata string literal

Tags: c, string-literals

I'm trying to whip up a demo where I change the value of a string literal by using mprotect.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {
        char* ptr = "Test\n";

        unsigned long sz = getpagesize() - 1;
        // And off any page offset bits
        void *pg = (void *) ((long) ptr & ~sz);

        // This tells the OS that a page is readable/write
        mprotect(pg, strlen(ptr), PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ); 
        strcpy(ptr, "Darn\n"); 

        const char* ptr2 = "Test\n";

        assert(ptr == "Test\n");//
        assert(ptr == ptr2);

        printf("%s", ptr2);
        printf("Test\n");

        assert(ptr == "Test\n");
        assert(ptr == ptr2);
}
```

Since this demo runs without failing the asserts, ptr == ptr2 == "Test\n", and they should all point at the same memory in the .rodata. So why does the second print statement print "Test\n"?

The following also prints "Test\n"

```
printf("%s", "Test\n");
```

Comment: Have you inspected the generated assembly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077119/can-gcc-merge-duplicate-global-string-arrays

Comment: @HansPassant The -fmerge-all-constants
was related to what I was looking for, but I guess my question was why they were 2 different strings in the first place. It looks like under the hood printf is calling puts("Test"); to add a newline. Doing this whole thing with "Test" replacing "Test\n" (except in the printf) causes the expected behavior.

Comment: @Makyen Sorry about that, I didn't think about this as an issue (or an employer looking at my stack overflow history)

Comment: `len` argument to `mprotect` looks wrong. I guess you wanted to mprotect the whole page there?