# A question about c++ grammar [static const auto compare = [](const std::string& now, const std::string& next) noexcept ->bool ]

Tags: c++, static, constants, grammar, noexcept

```
static const auto compare = [](const std::string& now, const std::string& next) noexcept ->bool 
    {
        return now.size() == next.size() ? now < next : now.size() < next.size();
    };
```

I saw this code on Hacker rank and I do not understand how it works.

Q1. Why this guy used static const auto and const std::string
Q2. What does [] mean ?
Q3. Why string&? not string
Q4. what does noexcept -> bool mean?

Any comments would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is a lambda expression https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this should be answered or closed with a generic duplicate regarding lambda syntax, but there's so much going on here, I'm tempted to explain it step by step.

First of all, I suggest getting [a good book for learning C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (particularly one covering C++11), rather than HackerRank or any other "competitive programming" website. Code written there can rarely be called "good" and solutions provided by others (as you noticed) are commonly just to flex their own knowledge, not to share it with others.

What you see is a single *[lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)*. It defines a lambda called `compare`, which takes two `const std::string&` as arguments and returns `bool`. It is likely used later in a function from `<algorithm>` library. Simplifying, lambda is a short syntax for a function, which can be called later on somewhere else.

Lambda syntax is as follows:

```
[ capture-list ] ( parameters ) optional-qualifiers -> return-type { body }
```

Your lambda has:

- empty capture list (it operates only on the parameters provided each call)
- two arguments of type `const std::string&`, which are passed with every call to lambda.
- `noexcept` qualifier - programmer promises that no exceptions will be thrown by this lambda
- return type `bool`
- body of single line `return now.size() == next.size() ? now < next : now.size() < next.size();`

Regarding variable `compare`, there are several keywords used to define it:

- `static` strongly depends on context - it means something different in class scope and in namespace scope. [Read more in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698043/static-variables-in-c)
- `const` is quite obvious - this variable will not change. Required to initialize `static` class members in place.
- `auto` - let the compiler deduce type of variable. Lambdas don't have any common name for type, so `auto` or `std::function<>` are only options one can use.

Finally:

> Q3. Why string&? not string

Why not? There is absolutely no reason to copy arguments into lambda, so it's much faster to pass them by reference. More on that topic: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Lambda Expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

The syntax used here is

> [ captures ] ( params ) -> ret { body }

You can think about lambda as a an any variable in `C++`

Q1. Why this guy used static const auto and const std::string?

A1. `static const auto` has the same meaning as for `static const auto x = 1;`, `const std::string` to prevent modification of the argument inside the lambda body.

Q2. What does [] mean?

A2. This is a syntax for lambda captures, you can specify what will be visible inside the lambda body.

Q3. Why string&?

A3. Passing `std::string` by reference to avoid copy.

Q4. what does noexcept -> bool mean?

A4. [noexcept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) tells the compiler that code does not throw exceptions. `-> bool` is lambda's return code.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Why this guy used static const auto and const std::string

Why not? I am not the author, so I cannot answer that accurately. Without context, I cannot even make a reasonable guess.

> Q2. What does [] mean ?

It is part of the syntax of the lambda expression. It is the capture list, and it is empty.

> Q3. Why string&? not string

Presumably because copying strings is potentially slow.

> Q4. what does noexcept -> bool mean?

Noexcept means that the function is not allowed to throw. -> bool is the return type of the function.