# Linking namespaces across different files with different classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to have a namespace that is defined in multiple files that I can use in multiple header and implementation files. For example:

Suppose I have a header file called `test1.h` as follows:

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<memory>
#include<map>

namespace A {
inline std::string getAString () { 
std::string mystring{"test1"};
  return mystring; }
}
```

Then I have another header file, `test2.h`, which declares a class and extends the above namespace:

```
#pragma once
#include "test1.h"

class MyClass {
public:
  std::string get_MyClassString() { return A::getAString();}
};

typedef std::map<std::string, MyClass> mymaptype;

namespace A {
static std::shared_ptr<mymaptype> mapptr = std::make_shared<mymaptype>();
}
```

I then have a third header file, `test3.h` that declares another class :

```
#pragma once
#include "test1.h"
//#include "test2.h"

class MyClass2 {
public:
  void testfunction();
};
```

and finally an implementation file, `test3.cpp`:

```
#include "test3.h"

void MyClass2::testfunction() {
  std::string nstr{"test1"};
  auto& mptr = A::mapptr->at(nstr);
};
```

This doesn't compile because I have not included `test2.h` in `test3.h`. i.e. there is "no member named 'mymaptype' in namespace 'A'".

If I include `test2.h` in `test3.h` I get redefinition issues. The reason that I need multiple files is that I have several classes that need to be defined before I can use them in the namespace and then there are several classes that may rely on one or more those previous classes.

Exact error message when compiled with `g++ -g -Wall test3.cpp test.o`:

```
test3.cpp: In member function ‘void MyClass2::testfunction()’:
test3.cpp:5:19: error: ‘mapptr’ is not a member of ‘A’                                                                        5 |   auto& mptr = A::mapptr->at(nstr);
```

Comment: **I get redefinition issues.** Post the verbatim errors.

Comment: Where are your include guards?

Comment: Did you forget `#pragma once` in `test1.h`?

Comment: `static std::shared_ptr<mymaptype> mapptr = std::make_shared<mymaptype>();` is a bad idea in a header.

Comment: @273K "In member function 'void MyClass2::testfunction()':, error: 'mymap'type is not a member of 'A'. Compiling with `g++ -g -Wall test3.cpp -o test.o`

Comment: @fatm Please [edit] your question to add the full error message. Code in comments in unreadable.

Comment: I am not getting redefinition issues unless I include `test2.h` in `test3.h`

Comment: And well, the error is correct. `mymaptype` is not in `namespace A`, it's in the global namespace.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes you are right, my mistake a typing error, I have corrected it. But I still get the same error with `mapptr` which is in namespace A.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Why? I want the shared pointer to exist, as well as all references, until the end of the program. Any other reasons?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I have added this and there is no change. Yes there is no main so a minor complaint is expected.

Comment: If you include that file in `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` how many objects are created?

Comment: @RetiredNinja My understanding (which could well be wrong) is that there should be one object created, because of the `static` keyword, and then I can have multiple pointers and a reference counter to it. But I am learning here ...

Comment: [In header files, what is the difference between a static global variable and a static data member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698043/in-header-files-what-is-the-difference-between-a-static-global-variable-and-a-s) is worth a read. I general it is best to avoid global variables if you can. You might consider using the Singleton pattern instead but that is really just a global with a fancy name.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I tried that initially (i.e. Singleton pattern) where the original class was a `config class`. I may try a struct to contain the pointers to my global members.

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/aKGx4KM8b

Comment: @Jabberwocky You actually have to put them in different files. Putting them all in a single file does not reproduce the error. That is why I was wondering if it was a linker error.

Comment: @fatm with different files I cannot reproduce it either, at least not with the MS C++ compiler.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I don't know then? I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and compiling with the latest version of g++.

Comment: Re. `"Exact error message when compiled with g++ -g -Wall test3.cpp test.o ..."`: where did `test.o` come from? Is that *really* your compile/link command?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you've posted `test2.h` and `test3.h` both include `test1.h`. Since `test1.h` has no include guard this will result in multiple definitions of the same symbol.

Comment: I am not getting any redefinition issues and adding `#pragma once` to `test1.h` has no effect.

Comment: Ok if you’re not getting redefinition issues please post the error message you do get without the line ‘#include “test2.h”’ commented out. The error message you’ve posted isn’t helpful because it’s correct, there is no definition of that symbol.